# rendered page completely changes, after adding a call to `render`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I currently have this in my controller;

```
  def get_response
    response = HTTParty.get('url')
    render json: response.to_json
  end

  def edit
    @newevent = Event.find(params[:id])
     json = get_response

    byebug
  end
```

Now when I go to the edit page, it just shows the json response, which is not what I want.

I want the response to be usable via the edit page. So I could call response. `ID` (currently isn't working, but like I said, I can get json back and to show, just it removed my edit page, which is not what I want as I want the json to be used inside the edit page)

Comment: could you clarify your questions? i see one problem there: `render json ` doesn't need `.to_json` on the content. that's what `render json` does automatically.

Comment: The question is, How can i call this without it chaning the edit page to the response?

Answer (score 0):

After rereading several times, I think I understand the problem.

## What happened

I think what is confusing you is the Rails magic™, that is so handy and yet makes it super hard for beginners to make the step from using Rails generated code to their own versions and understand why stuff breaks.

A controller action that is empty like `edit` was, will do an implicit `render <name-of-controller-action>`. As soon as you write an actual `render` yourself, Rails will not do the implicit `render`. So what you did is actually 'overwrite' the Rails one. Yielding the result of you seeing your JSON rendered and not the edit page anymore.

## How to solve it

What you are trying to do is adding extra content to your edit view (that you first get from some other webpage). Using `render` is on several levels the wrong approach. (I suggest rereading the Rails guides, since I think some concepts are not yet clear to you).

What you want to do is building upon the existing edit view (`edit.html.erb`). You want to add the content somewhere in that view and of course need to prepare that in the controller so the view can access it.

So in your controller you might do something along the lines of `@website_content = HTTParty.get('url')` meaning in your view you can use `@website_content` to display the JSON you downloaded.